# Creating a copy of a task with different configuration values

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I have a gradle task that I would like to have 2 different versions of. The task is a custom task called "migrate", which will apply database migrations in order to later generate database classes.

I want to create a copy of this with different configurations to apply the migrations to a local database.

Currently, I have:

```
task migrateLocal(type: com.me.tasks.ApplyMigrationsTask) {
  port = 3306
  dbName = "me"
  host = 'localhost'
  migrationsDirectoryPath = project.layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/main/resources/me/migrations")
}
```

However, I get an error `Cannot cast object '3306' with class 'java.lang.Integer' to class 'org.gradle.api.provider.Provider'`

Upon further investigation, I attempted to do:

```
task migrateLocal(type: com.me.tasks.ApplyMigrationsTask) {
  port.set(3306)
  dbName.set("me")
  host.set('localhost')
  migrationsDirectoryPath.set(project.layout.projectDirectory.dir("src/main/resources/me/migrations"))
}
```

But then I get an error like: `Cannot get the value of write-only property 'port' for task 'migrateLocal'`

What would be the correct way to do this? I haven't been able to find documentation on this pattern or these errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a public Gradle plugin? Where does the ApplyMigrationsTask come from?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do that.

One way is to define generic tasks per config:

```
def configs = ["C1", "C2"]
configs.each{ cfg -> 

    // call this using migrateLocalC1 or migrateLocalC2 
    task "migrateLocal${cfg}"{
        description 'some generic task'
        // do magic
    }
}
```

You could then further define globally for example `def dbNameC1="me"` and retrieve/set that in the respective task via `dbName = ${dbname${cfg}}` (this happens at `// do magic` in my example).

A different way, which in my opinion is more appropriate in your situation, is to store these attributes in a config, specifically you can throw this into `gradle.properties`. You can for example place a property `dbName=me` and then load it in your Gradle task via `${dbName}`. Just remember, these are set on configuration, not on script execution. Additionally you can look into `ext`.